# Input not appearing when executing function

Tags: javascript, php

I need that when the option "otros" of a select is clicked, an input appears. To do so, I have made this script which is not working fine (input does not appear).

**html/php**

```
<select onclick='atencion_otros()' id="atencion" name="atencion">
    <option selected>Atención</option>
    <option>Otros</option>
    <?php if($copy){ echo '<option selected>' . $atencion . '</option>';
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `contactos_pmt` ORDER BY nombre_contacto");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
     ?> <option> <?php echo $row['nombre_contacto']; ?> </option>
     <br><br><?php
     }
    }
    if($cargar_cliente){
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `contactos_pmt` WHERE 
    nombre_empresa = '$nombre_cliente' ORDER BY nombre_contacto");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
     ?> <option selected> <?php echo $row['nombre_contacto']; ?> </option>
     <br><br><?php
     }
    }
    ?>
</select>
<input onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;" style="display:none;" id="atencion_otros" name="atencion_otros" placeholder="Atención" />
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function atencion_otros() {
    if (document.getElementById('atencion').value == 'Otros') {
        document.getElementById('atencion_otros').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('atencion_otros').style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
</script>
```

Do you have any idea of why the input is not appearing?

Comment: maybe try `onchange()` ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange

Comment: give value to your options `<option value="Otros">Otros</option>`

Comment: @okante — In the absence of a value attribute, the value will be the text content of the element

Comment: Why are you clogging up the question with PHP? The problem doesn't appear to have anything to do with PHP. Provide a [mcve] with the plain HTML instead.

Comment: @delboy1978uk not working with onchange(). Thank you

Comment: @Quentin you're Right

Comment: As already commented above you need to give value attribute to your select options. Then onclick event is not right choice, use onchange event. With onchange event binding you can ensure the change in value is reflected.

Comment: Side note: looks like your `<select>` will end up with `<br>`s between some of the `<option>`s. Don't think that's valid. Not sure it'll have any visual effect either. Also you'll likely have more than one option with the "selected" attribute set at one time, which makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add value attributes in all your `<option>`.

Then add event Listener.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function() {
    document.getElementById('atencion').onchange=atencion_otros;
},false);
```

now your function

```
function atencion_otros() {
    if (document.getElementById('atencion').value == 'Otros') {
        document.getElementById('atencion_otros').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('atencion_otros').style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
```

Now remove onclick attribute from your `<select>`.